# Choosing best fit regression model from root MSE and adjusted R squared

Tags: regression, r-squared, mse

I run regression model and wanted to choose the best fit model among 3 regression models.

```
Model   Root MSE    Adj R
1       18.08      0.8769
2       23.97      0.8868
3       28.19      0.894
```

Which could be the best fit model? MSE is smallest for Model 1 but R2 is highest for Model 3.

Comment: Welcome Odi. On this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end of your post. It might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site ([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions".

Comment: Greg Snow's answer in this [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90908/f-values-in-anova-table) will give you some idea of how to test which of those models is sufficient. Note that this assumes that your models are nested.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Select Model 3.

The adjusted $R^2$ makes a compromise between how good the model fits the data and how complex the model is. I assume Model 3 is simpler than Model 1. Simpler is better.

### Longer answer

$MSE$, $RMSE$, $R^2$ and such measures of error just compare datasets and see how different they are. However, a model that is simpler is more likely to be useful in different situations than those represented by the training data.

That takes us to the next issue: You either:

a) Use a different set of data to select your model (not training data!)

or:

b) Use a different way to select it, one that gives you hints that your model will behave better in other situations. I speak of [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)), for instance.

Other ways to compare models take into account it's complexity, penalizing the number of parameters in the model. Your adjusted $R^2$ falls in this category, but there are [other measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). The keyword here is [model selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection).